# In which episode is this scene with two Zoros?

Tags: one-piece

I recently stumbled upon a One Piece pic which left me dumbfounded. In the picture below you can clearly see that 2 Zoros appear at the same time, being a One Piece fan myself I wasn't able to remember when that happened. Does any of you guys in which episode (or special or movie) did this happen?

[image]

Thanks for your help as always :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be an animation error from an earlyish episode when that was more frequent.  Specifically it comes from [Episode 226](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BeXKZ01z5aQ) which is part of the Foxy Pirate Crew Arc.

In this scene Zoro is fighting Foxy the Silver Fox in (a bad) disguise to the left hand side of the screen and also (apparenly) calmly standing there watching the silly fight.